# Telethon: AttributeError: 'MessageMediaPhoto' object has no attribute 'document'

Tags: python, async-await, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to run this Telegram image downloader:
https://github.com/fabifrank/telegram-image-downloader

When I run it I get an error:
`AttributeError: 'MessageMediaPhoto' object has no attribute 'document'`

The code looks like this:

```
    if(debug_enabled):
        print(update)
    if update.message.media is not None:
        file_name = 'unknown name';
        attributes = update.message.media.document.attributes
        for attr in attributes:
            if isinstance(attr, types.DocumentAttributeFilename):
                file_name = attr.file_name
        print("[%s] Download queued at %s" % (file_name, time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())))
        message = await update.reply('In queue')
        await queue.put([update, message])
```

I'm using Python 3.10

Answer (score 0):

That's because MessageMediaPhoto does not have document but MessageMediaDocument has. I had the same issue and I used continue to skip through the exception.

```
async for message in takeout.iter_messages(channel,  wait_time=0):   
    try:
        print(message.media.document)
    except:
        continue
```

This will print out the document name if there is any otherwise it will show nothing. Hope it helps!